# HTML e CSS: Inserir span dentro da Option Select

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte Select:

[image: Span dentro da Option Select]

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma, mas não consegui:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>
        <a title="Alimentação">
            <span class="color" style="display: block; width:20px; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);"></span>
            <span class="label">Alimentação</span>
        </a>
    </option>
    ...
</select>
```

Dessa forma apareceu somente o texto, a cor não.

Comment: Não pode ter HTML dentro de option. Você vai ter que construir seu próprio select do zero com js

Comment: Exatamente: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-option-element